# Magento SOAP API V1 changing soap:address location

Tags: api, magento, soap

We have a multistore magento setup thats still half in development. But we have 1 of the stores open with a test url.

e.g
test.domain.com

However when we go to: http://test.domain.com/index.php/api/index/?wsdl=1 
I noticed that soap:address shows the main domain not the api url e.g:

```
<soap:address location="https://www.domain.com/index.php/api/index/index/?SID=vnl0ijdobf6ldj76pmc658rj92"/>
```

Which atm isn't live.
We have no issues with 3rd parties who come in on the V2 api but this doesn't seem to have a `soap:address` which I believe is the problem.

When I go to: http://test.domain.com/index.php/api/index/?wsdl=1 in a browser it shows xml. 
 
When I try and make a soap call i get: `looks like we got no XML document`.

When I update my local hosts file with the new ip to point at the domain it will work. 
But the 3rd party can't update their server because its shared hosting. Is there a way to change the API to point at the api url and not the base store url?